# Image not displaying in Jykell

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, prose

### Question

I am trying using the `Github Page + Jykell now + Prose.io` combination for a personal webpage / journal. I have also did the CNAME setting so my domain will apply.

I insert the image using `markdown`:

```
![my journey]({{site.baseurl}}/_posts/journey-4.jpg)
```

which generates `html` as follows:

```
<img src="journey-4.jpg" alt="my journey">
```

### Issue

The image shows up in `Prose` but not github page.

Prose:
[image]

**Github Page:**
[image]

### Deduction

I kind of understand the image missing is due to the domain name being applied. i.e.

```
{github+username}/_posts/journey-4.jpg <-- actual location
```

```
{my.domain.com}/_post/journey-4.jpg <-- after the CNAME bit applied
```

And it could be resolved by using absolute (raw) address from Github.

However, this will defeat the purpose of using Prose to "easily" manage the image upload because each image updated, the corresponding raw address has to be found.

Is it part of the side-effecting using CNAME to apply the domain name? Am I setting up the `Github Page + Jykell now + Prose.io` combo incorrectly?

Comment: What does the actual generated HTML look like? i.e. when you view source on the page in both contexts, what does the img tag have as a src?

Comment: I think it would be easier if I show you the actual link [here](http://marco-leong.com/Journey-so-far/)

Comment: That will not necessarily help people in future to get value from the answer, though.

Comment: no problem, i have added the `html` code generated in the question. I will put it here here as well: `<img src="journey-4.jpg" alt="my journey">` from `![my journey]({{site.baseurl}}/_posts/journey-4.jpg)`